# Why aren't subdominant (IV) triads the same in both major and minor?

Tags: chord-theory

For my choir theory assignment, I was looking at tonic (I/i), subdominant (IV/iv), and dominant (V/v) triads in both major and minor. What I wanted to know is why are IV and iv different when V and v are the same? I know that the 5th is perfect, so I thought that could be why dominant doesn't change, but there's also a perfect 4th. I tried asking this and the response I got was "it just is," so I thought I'd ask on here! Thank you!!

Answer (score 9):

Your premise is incorrect - V and v are not the same. In classical music and in common practice period harmony, **v is not treated as a dominant-function chord** and is pretty much never directly followed by the tonic. This is unlike V, the quintessential dominant-function chord. There's also the more obvious part where **v is a minor chord, while V is a major chord**.

Thus, it makes a lot of sense that IV and iv are also different. Heck, IV and iv often have the same harmonic function and are therefore more similar than V and v.

Answer (score 7):

V and v are not the same. Capital V is a major chord and it tastes stronger than a lower-case v chord, when heading to a minor tonic.

You can also have a capital IV while still having a minor tonic. It works like a subdominant, but tastes a bit different. Am D E7 Am.

In a minor key your tonic chord is a minor chord. In a major key your tonic chord is a major chord. All other chords can be literally *anything*. They just sound different and produce a different mood.

Go ahead and try it. If your song has a minor chord as [any chord degree or role], make it a major. Or the other way around. Sounds different! Take a song that's in a major key, and change all ii chords to II. Make changes, and it will sound different. Not good, not bad, not right, not wrong, just different.

Comment: Love the use of 'taste'!

Answer (score 3):

Minor scale chords are built using the harmonic minor scale. This produces a sharpened 7th - but not a flattened 6th - so that the dominant chord is major, not minor - which is more suited to traditional classical music and produces a perfect cadence.

A dominant chord that is minor produces a modal sound. In 20th century English music, when modal music became more studied, often a minor dominant chord was used in a major scale, e.g. G minor in C major. Although beautiful when used by the really good composers, unfortunately this sometimes became an affectation to create an instant Elizabethan sound.

Things are more complicated in pre-classical harmony as sometimes different ascending and descending versions of the mode were used simultaneously, often producing clashes. For example, in the key of D an ascending phrase B natural, C#, D may be used in one voice and D, C natural, Bb in another. A later example of this can be found in the slow movement of Bach's Italian Concerto where a B natural in an ascending scale is played against a Bb chord (part of a descending harmonic sequence).

The use of a major subdominant chord in a minor key became used a lot in rock and disco - play Cm7 and F9 and the style is instantly recognisable. Also many guitar solos on Pink Floyd tracks used a similar sequence.

Comment: Triads can be built on scale degrees from any scale. Why do you think *only* the harmonic minor counts? Your 3rd para. refers to melodic minor - a scale in its own right, which isn't a mode, although it has modes of its own.

Comment: I did not suggest it was a mode, I was putting it in a context.

Comment: These are some good related ideas (like chromatic clashes), but I think this answer needs more interpretation/explanation, like how minor v has expressive meaning rather than just being "not allowed".

Comment: "Minor scale chords" ... I don't like the choice of words. You might mean "minor key chords", but that would be misleading as well. There are several minor scales and each of them has chords, but what can be derived from a scale doesn't mean anything, unless you want to enforce a mode by not having any chromatic alterations anywhere. Pieces in minor keys do not have to stick to any set of notes or chords, as long as the sense of a minor tonic chord stays somewhat clear. You can have Cm - Fm - F - Cm - Db - D7 - Gm - G7 - Cm. Scale degrees change along the way, it's perfectly normal and fine.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica pieces in modes don't necessarily need to stick to any set of notes or chords either; that distinction between modal and tonal music is modern.  Modal music of the renaissance and baroque certainly did not observe it.

Comment: @phoog If the harmony has chromatic alterations, not only as short passing notes but harmonically significant, then I say that the mode changes, and if the mode seems to change all the time rapidly then I wouldn't talk about modes at all. Do you have a different opinion? I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica here's an example: how would you analyze _[Christus, der uns selig macht](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJwpO2qycGg)_ from Bach's St. John Passion?  I would not say that the mode changes.  What do you think?

Comment: @phoog This doesn't seem like a short discussion, maybe take it to the chat?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica sure.  The [main room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the rationale is voice-leading. In species counterpoint (which is admittedly a pedagogical invention), the penultimate interval must be a major sixth or equivalent (i.e {Re Ti} -> {Do do} or {Ra Te} -> {Do do} for Phrygian).

This voice leading requirement held over into the development of chord progressions, so when you  play the **V** chord in a minor key, you have to sharpen the Te to Ti to allow {Ti Re} to form that major sixth. Compared to the **v** chord, which contains {Te Re}, the notes are much closer to where they "want" to go.

In comparison, the **IV/iv** chord does not have the same role, as it doesn't contain Ti/Te or Re/Ra, so there's no reason to sharpen it. If anything, in a plagal cadence, Le of the **iv** chord would want to resolve down to So, which arguably makes the **iv** chord "better" for resolving to the **I** chord. (Though that can also make iv-V stronger as well.)

In either case, switching between major and minor is not simply a matter of the correct version of the chord, but rather, as Dekkadeci notes, the different quality chords have different harmonic function, which is derived from the motion of the individual voices in the chord.

Comment: Does "or equivalent" to the major sixth include the minor third?  Also, iv-V progressions are very common, even characteristic.  It is only necessary to prefer IV over iv if there is some need for the third of the subdominant and dominant to appear in the same voice.

Answer (score 1):

Triads are taken from the notes in particular scales. I = 135, IV = 468 and V = 579. In key C, they equate to CEG, FAC, and GBD.

Depending on which minor scale notes one uses, i = 135, iv = 468 and v = 579. And that's where the descrepancy lies. 135 ( in key Cm) will be CE♭G, iv is FA♭C, but V(v) could be either GBD *or* (GB♭D).

However (there's often 'however'), if one uses the notes from the *melodic* minor, ascending (or jazz), since those scale notes are C D E♭ F G A B, then your idea will work - the IV in key Cm will be F major, just as in key C major. Note that capital RN denote *major*, while lower case (v) denotes *minor*. Armed with that, V and v will never be the same! Explain that to your tutor - he'll be well impressed !

Comment: I think the explanation is the other way around: the variability of the 6th and 7th degrees of the minor scale is based on the observation that we use both the V and v (and IV and iv) chords in minor. The chords (or voice leading) came before the scale.

Comment: I would say this is backwards. The reason why the B is natural and not flat is, because we want to have a G _major_ chord. The chord is NOT what it is because of a scale forced it to be that way. The scale is because of the chord. LOL @awelotta said the same thing at the same time. Maybe it could be generalized even more by saying that we want to have a strong push towards tonic, and that can only be had by a major seventh note. The dominant chord is an embodiment of the leading tone, and a five-one jump. The scales are just pitch grids constructed to fit over the chords without grid changes.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - could well be! But I used the *notes* from the particular minor scales not so much to say that's where they came from (although in a way, that's actually where they came from) but as a place where those notes existed. If OP knew that, the question wouldn't have arisen.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is in the note values and their intervals themselves. The natural minor scale is a mode of the major.

Given a major scale and its degrees:

```
I ii iii IV V vi viio
```

The relative minor scale simply starts the cycle on the vi

```
              vi viio I   ii iii IV V
```

Since we have changed the root, `vi` becomes the tonic `i` and we renumber everything from there. But the moods (major/minor/diminished) must obviously stay the same. Nothing is changing, other than where we start the Roman numbering:

```
              i  iio  III iv v   VI VII
```

As you can see, `v` is minor in the natural minor scale; it is not the same as `V`. We get a dominant `V`/`V7` harmony in the minor scale/key when we introduce it as an alteration. It arises in the melodic and harmonic minor modes which promote the use of dominant-based harmonic devices.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `I` change of course when the *mediant* scale degree changes between minor and major. This is the primary tone determining major or minor scale/key quality.

`v` (lower case for minor triad) and `V` change when the seventh scale degree is either in the "lowered" form, which means it is a whole step below the *tonic* and called the *subtonic*, or in the "raised" form, which is a half step below the tonic and called the *leading tone*. The leading tone is the scale degree that actually creates the true dominant function, note that the diminished triad built on the leading tone is often called the "leading tone triad." In the major/minor harmonic system tonality is created primary by the tonic/dominant relationship. Even in minor keys the seventh degree is raised to make a leading tone for the `V` chord, because the movement of the leading tone to the tonic is essential for the tonality.

Now we get to the subdominant minor triad `iv` versus the major `IV`. Why is it one or the other? First, the minor triad is used, because in minor keys the two *modal* scale degrees *mediant* and *sub-mediant* are a *minor* third and *minor* sixth above the tonic respectively, and the minor sub-mediant is the chordal third of `iv`. Why then might the subdominant be a major triad `IV` in a minor key? A likely reason will be about *voice leading* and *raising* the sub-mediant along with the leading tone where the harmony has one of the voices moving in the ascending line `♯^6 ♯^7 ^1`.

Major `IV` seems to be much less common than `iv`. A lot of this is explained in terms of voice leading. Voice leading patterns using the melodic pairs `^5 ♭^6 ^5` and `^1 ♯^7 ^1` are really common, more than the full ascent `^5 ♯^6 ♯^7 ^1`. So, the more common `♭^6` ends up forming the more common `iv` chord.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `v` is a minor chord, and `V` is a major chord. **The name fully defines the chord, irrespective of whether it is used within a minor or major scale**: A small letter always means a minor chord, a big letter means a major chord (unless a small "m" is attached, in which case it's minor again).

---

So why is there confusion about whether the dominant in a minor scale is minor or major? Well, there are a few different aspects:

- The function of a dominant is to lead to the tonic. One big part of that leading tension is, that its third is only a half step away from the tonic *if it is major*. The minor `v` does not have this property. Since many composers want the leading function of the dominant to be strong, they frequently use the major `V` chord even in a minor scale.
- The minor scale is frequently modified by raising the 7th to be major (harmonic minor). This is the same note that acts as the third in the dominant chord, turning the `v` into a `V`.
- The minor scale can further be modified to also raise the 6th to be major, but only on the ascent (melodic minor). When descending, the natural minor scale is used. A piece in this scale may use all of `iv`, `IV`, `v` and `V` in quick succession.
- Composers generally don't feel too attached to the minor mode anyways. One frequent example is the use of `I` instead of `i` at the end of a minor piece. Expect a lot of artistic freedom to be exercised when it comes to compositions in minor. A composer may decide to introduce non-scale chords at any point in a piece, and sometimes it actually sounds great. And that is what composers care about, not whether they are in perfect compliance to some theoretic rules!

As you see, the truth is quite involved, and simple answers are only lies to children. But the notation of the chords is simple: Small letter, minor chord; big letter, major chord. It's been devised precisely to describe all these corner cases faithfully.

Comment: Melodic minor (jazz) uses the old ascending notes both ways.